# os.listdir() showing file actually not in the folder on Python and Windows

Tags: windows, filesystems, desktop.ini

The following Python script:

```
import os
print os.listdir('D:\images')
```

is outputing the names of all the folders in the `D:\image` directory, but it is also showing `desktop.ini` in the same folder, while there is no such file in the image directory.

Its also not a hidden item, I am sure of that.

Why is it then showing it as a content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`desktop.ini` is a protected system file, and Windows tends to hide it.

You can verify by going to `D:\images` in a terminal and running `dir /A`.

See [this](https://superuser.com/a/487718/135900) answer as well.

You can use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) if you want more control, it will give you directories and files separately. You can  also use [`os.path.isdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) to find out if an entry you get is a directory.

Comment: Can I delete it from there? Its causing my program to halt before scanning all the folders in D:\images\ .

Comment: added some edits. it's safe to delete, but Windows might add it back. the correct thing to do is to handle it in a predictable way.

Comment: Can you tell how I could have used os.walk() to determine if the item is a directory or not?

Comment: For each directory, it gives you a `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)` tuple, in which directories and files are separate. It will also walk the whole tree.

Answer (score 0):

I used **os.path.isdir(path)** to check whether the item returned by os.listdir() is a directory or not

This way,**desktop.ini** didn't meet the criteria of being a directory and my program scanned all the folders.